# Spotfire bulk removal of disabled users from groups

Tags: spotfire, user-management

Is there a way to remove all the disabled users from all the groups those users belong to ?

Comment: Are you using integrated authentication? Is it tied to AD if so?

Comment: yes, it is, yes